# prelude 80 column dispay off

Tags: prelude

How can I as an emacs prelude (-nw) user turn off the 80 column warning highlight seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That effect comes from `whitespace-mode`, [enabled by default](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/core/prelude-editor.el#L325) in Prelude.

If you want to keep the effect but set it at a different column, you can set `whitespace-line-column` to a value you like. If you want to disable the effect, remove `lines-tail` from `whitespace-style`.

Make these changes in your `~/.emacs` or `init.el` (which ever one you use). Something like the following would keep Prelude's default `whitespace-mode` settings but disable "greater than 80 column highlighting":

```el
;; Change Prelude's default whitespace-mode settings
(setq whitespace-style '(face tabs empty trailing))
```

And the following should disable all `whitespace-mode` styling:

```el
;; Turn off whitespace-mode styling
(setq whitespace-style nil)
```

If you don't care about `whitespace-mode` at all, you could unload it:

```el
;; Disable whitespace-mode entirely
(unload-feature whitespace-mode)
```

Although, if another library relies on `whitespace-mode`, it may not be able to be unloaded.

Comment: please expand on what you meant by "remove lines-tail from whitespace-style"

Comment: You can also edit `whitespace-style` by `M-x customize-variable`, then `whitespace-style`.